# How to check if current user is exist in a AD group inside a Sharepoint group

Tags: spuser

I have a sharepoint permission group with some permissionslevels. The name is: "SPProgress". Inside this group I have inserted a AD usergroup  with the name "ADProgress".

I would like to check in code if the current user is exist in the SharePoint permision group "SPProgress". But if the current user is exist in the AD usergroup "ADProgress", it needs to return true.

I set the currentuser outside the `RunWithElevatedPrivileges` in a parameter.

```
SPUser currentUser = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
SPGroup someGroup = somegroup...

SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                            {

if(IsUserExistInGroup(currentUser, someGroup ))
{
// do some logic
}
}
```

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using CurrentUser and if you create the a SPWeb object outside of the runwithelevatedprivileges this code should work for you for the SharePoint group:

```
web.IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(someGroup.ID);
```

Since you are using the current user, this code should work for you for the AD group:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("domain\\ADProgress");
```

Comment: I am looking for some solution for inside the runwithelevatedprivileges.

Comment: Why can't you run this within runwithelevatedprivileges??? Just use the web object created outside runwithelevatedprivileges so it will use the currently logged in user.

Comment: I am looking for some solution with SPUser and SPGroup as parameters. With these 2 parameters inside the RunWithElevatedPrivileges I would like to check the membership.

Comment: Right, that should be fine.  The issue comes with you CREATE the spweb or spsite object inside the runwithelevatedprivileges.  When that happens the service account is what is assigned to the usertoken and when you try to check permissions they always return true.